# Visual Studio Code + Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Установил portable версию Python 3.6 (указана как совместимая с Windows 10) и Visual Studio Code. Добавил в переменные окружения все пути

**переменная PATH**

[image: Перемененная PATH]

**Переменная PYTHONPATH**

[image: Переменная PYTHONPATH]

При работе в VS Code (расширение Python от Microsoft) скрипты выполняются, но не видит IDE отладчик:

```
    pydev debugger: CRITICAL WARNING: This version of python seems to be incorrectly compiled (internal generated filenames are not absolute)
pydev debugger: The debugger may still function, but it will work slower and may miss breakpoints.
pydev debugger: Related bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue1666807
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: tokenize.py
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: codecs.py
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: urllib\parse.py
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: queue.py
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: C:\Users\abukreev\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: threading.py
0b111001
```

Перерыл все настройки, не могу понять где прописать путь до установленного Python

Comment: Говорят, может твой pyc файл плохой. Попробуй удалить и запустить:
find . -name '*.pyc' -delete

Comment: В проекте нет файлов *.pyc. Ошибка возникает на любом куске кода, файле и т.д.